# wordpress post loop, get multiple pages

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I like to get Wordpress post page 2 and 3 for example. I can't get it to work. any idea how to do this?

```
query_posts( array('posts_per_page' => 4, paged => array(4,5) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

query_posts returns array so you can check if it works by using var_dump(); ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/ )

Also in the array you have problem with typo (hint: '')

But in my opinion the better way to do this will be get_posts() ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts )